# Conceptual question about cosine similarity and clustering algorithms for word embeddings

Tags: clustering, word-embeddings, cosine-distance

Is the following statement true? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/256778

> The value of cosine similarity between two terms itself is not indicator whether they are similar or not.

If yes then how is use of clustering algorithms like DBSCAN for word embeddings justified? From what I know DBSCAN algorithm only looks to its immediate neighbour to be included in cluster, but it seems the wrong way since maybe we need to check every word with every other word and take top ranked words.

Comment: Welcome to DS. The question needs more context. Where does the statement come from, to what does it refer exactly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question with links and more clarity regarding my doubt.